# How do I select multiple rows in an html table by pressing ctrl key or shift key?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple html table where the rows are dynamically created and values are inserted into the cells. This is the code:

```
var table=document.getElementById("emp");

var row=table.insertRow(0);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
cell.innerHTML="<b>Name:</b>";
cell1.innerHTML="<b>Age:</b>";
cell2.innerHTML="<b>Address:</b>";

var row1=table.insertRow(1);
var cell3=row.insertCell(0);
var cell4=row.insertCell(1);
var cell5=row.insertCell(2);
cell3.innerHTML="Alex";
cell4.innerHTML=23;
cell5.innerHTML="Chicago";
```

Now, I want to be able to select multiple rows in my table, using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>. How do I do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check inside your click handler if a key is pressed and if so, perform the appropriate action

```
const trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
trs.forEach(tr => tr.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.shiftKey); // Will print true if shift is pressed.
}))
```